# How can I set ScriptLevel to be 0 for inline math mode?

Tags: stylesheet

I hate small integral signs and thus I like ScriptLevel to be 0.  I have set ScriptLevel to be 0 for Text cells, DisplayFormula, and InlineFormula.  When in a text cell I press ctrl+( to create an inline math mode cell (for lack of better term).  When I do this I notice in the option inspector that ScriptLevel is 1 and this causes a small integral sign to be typed.

In Mathematica 8 this did not happen.  It was ScriptLevel 0.  In Mathematica 9 is 1 and I haven't been able to figure how to change it to be 0 by default.  I've noticed a number of odd behaviors changed in the new Default.nb and this seems to be one of them.  I'm using OS X 10.7.2.

When using my notebooks created under Mathematica 8 I get the correct behavior.  But not when using new notebooks created in Mathematica 9.

Comment: The inline math mode using Ctrl-( is typeset using the `TraditionalForm` style. You can try setting `ScriptLevel` to 0 for that. I can't test right now

Comment: In additional to @Hypnotoad suggestion you can also use the V8 default stylesheet from within V9.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I'll try that.  I don't see where TraditionalForm is defined in the default stylesheet.  I have set DefaultNewInlineCellStyle for my Text cells to be "DisplayFormula" and have set ScriptLevel to 0 for "DisplayFormula".

Comment: @YequalsX **don't** edit the default stylesheet. Edit your private notebook stylesheet. Format>>Edit Stylesheet ... If you are unsure about how to do this search this site with key word(s) "stylesheet". In fact I remember answer a question that is related: had to change an option in TraditionalForm. Let me find it ...

Comment: @YequalsX i literally have to leave this minute but the post I am thinking of concerned a user that had unwanted background color for his tick labels so had to change TraditionalForm in his stylesheet.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I use a copy of Default.nb in my stylesheet.  I didn't actually change Default.nb.  I'll look for the post you speak of.  Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: You'll need to track back to the Core.nb stylesheet for settings of `TraditionalForm` as well as `InlineCell`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works on my Mathematica 9 by the following steps:

- Find the system stylesheet **Core.nb**
- Copy the `"InlineCell"` style from Core.nb into our own stylesheet
- Change value of `ScriptLevel` option in `"InlineCell"` style to `0`

Comment: Thank you for this information.  I did not know Core.nb had these definitions.

Comment: @YequalsX You are welcome :) This method should work for version 8 too. Usually I copy some styles from core.nb to my own stylesheet for some more customizing.